# ionic mouse scroll not working when using $scope.overflow_scroll='true'; in controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Directly set overflow-scroll="true" in html is no problem for mouse scroll on desktop browser.

```
<ion-content padding="true" overflow-scroll="true">
```

But use $scope.overflow_scroll='true'; in controller, and overflow-scroll="{{overflow_scroll}}" in html, the mouse scroll will not work on desktop browser.

```
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.overflow_scroll='true';
});
```

and

```
<ion-content padding="true" overflow-scroll="{{overflow_scroll}}">
```

[Here is the live demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjJvXo)

Any help would be much appreciated. Best Regards.